# Julia: Having a function by summing over an array of functions

Tags: function, julia

I have an array of functions and I want to make another function using a weighted sum over these functions. Let's say `T=[T1, ..., T20]`
and `T1(x,y)=x^2+5`, `T2(x,y)=sin(x+y)`, ...

I want to make another function named `g(x,y)=10*T1(x,y)+...+32*T20(x,y)`. the coefficients may change so I want to use some sort of loop but I couldn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is my try, probably there is a better solution.

If you can change the signature of g:

```
g(x, y, weights, T) = sum(weights[i]*Ti(x,y) for (i,Ti) in enumerate(T))
```

---

If you need exactly this signature `g(x,y)`, I suggest a generator function:

```
generate_g(weights, T) = (x,y) -> sum(weights[i]*Ti(x,y) for (i,Ti) in enumerate(T))
```

You pass the weights into it, and it returns a new function, that takes x and y as arguments. Here is an example

```
julia> T1(x,y)=x^2+5; T2(x,y)=sin(x+y); T=[T1, T2];

julia>g = generate_g([10,11], T)
#3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> g(1,2)
61.55232008865854
```

When the weights change, you can generate a new `g`.

Comment: This is a good solution and probably the best "simple" solution. Its only limitation is that it is not type stable, because the compiler does not know the return types of `Ti` at compile time. If performance is an issue you can either annotate `Ti(x,y)` with the expected return type or consider writing a macro that will generate the body of the function by unrolling the iteration over `T`.